# How to check text input for certain word(s) in js

Tags: javascript

```
<input id="ask" type="text">
<input id="submit" type="button" onclick="askQuestion">
<script>
    function askQuestion {
        if (document.getElementById('ask').value /*contains*/ "time"{
            /*tell time*/}
    }
</script>
```

Okay so I have something similar to the code above. The only thing I want to know is how do I check for if the "ask" textbox contains the word time? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: You could use `document.getElementById('ask').value.indexOf("time") >= 0`, or you could use a regular expression `/time/.test(document.getElementById('ask').value)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `bool contains = document.getElementById('ask').value.indexOf("time") > -1`

```
   function askQuestion {
        if (document.getElementById('ask').value.indexOf("time") > -1) {
            /*tell time*/}
    }
```